# PLSQL : Modify IN parameters of a procedure

Tags: plsql

I have procedure like this:

```
Procedure(var1 IN VARCHAR2, var2 IN VARCHAR2 ... )
---lines of code---
```

---inside this procedure i want to do the below

```
var1 := filter(var1); -- filter & assign to the same variable
....
....
--do something with var1
```

But the problem is am not able to modify a IN parameter to a procedure as its a constant.
The only option i can think of is to create/declare a new local variable & assign it the modified IN parameter & use it in the subsequent code.
But this is leading to clumsy code as there are nearly 30 IN parameters.So i need to create 30 new variables for each of them.

Need your help to change the IN parameter in a plsql procedure OR any other workaround to the above problem.

Regards
Vj

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you're trying to pass var1 as an OUT param into your filter function, which isn't allowed. The only options you have are:

- Make it an IN OUT parameter
- Assign it to a local variable

Comment: `IN OUT` would make the parameter required even with a `DEFAULT` attribute  I guess I'll use a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify var1, you will have to change the procedure specification to:

```
Procedure(var1 IN OUT VARCHAR2 ...
```

However, you said that there are nearly 30 IN parameters. If the data is related, why not create a custom record type?

```
-- use CREATE OR REPLACE if at the schema level
CREATE TYPE my_params_type IS RECORD(var1 type, var2 type ...);
```

Then your procedure...

```
Procedure(params IN my_params_type) IS
filtered_params my_params_type := params; 
BEGIN
  filterd_params.var1 := filter(params.var1);
  ...
```

something like that